# JQuery: How to Wildcard select visible element.Then get Selected Value

Tags: jquery, wildcard

I have a list of drop down lists populated form a database(using ASP.NET).

These drop down lists are ASP Controls, so selecting them by ID is not feasible.

They are named as such:

```
DD_Manufacturer1
DD_Manufacturer2
DD_Manufacturer3
```

These ASP.NET DropDown lists have a class that is the same as their name(EXAMPLE: DD_Manufacturer1's class is ="DD_Manufacturer1")

I am using a cascading dropdrop(We will call the ID of the first selection input MyList1).After a user selects  an option from MyList1, one of my ASP DropDowns becomes visible(Example: I chose Manufacturer1 in MyList1 and DD_Manufacuturer1 becomes visible)

Here is how it SHOULD work:

Manufacturer1 is chosen from MyList1
The selected value of MyList1 is passed on to hidden form field called dvMake
DD_Manufacturer1 becomes visible(This is an ASP.NET CONTROL)
User selects an option in DD_Manfacturer1
Selected value of DD_Manufacturer1 is passed on to hiddenfield called hidden-dvModel

Now, I am wanting to pass the selection of DD_Manufacturer1 onto a hiddenfield so it is easier to manipulate.

Here is my code so far:

```
function onModelChange() {
    $("#hidden-dvModel").remove(); //Removes Hidden Field if it already exists
    var dvMake = $("#hidden-dvMake").val(); //Get Make Value
    var ActiveMake = $("."+dvMake+""); //Derive Active DD List form Selected Make
    var ActiveMakeList = "DD_" + ActiveMake.attr('class') + "";
    alert(ActiveMakeList);//Succesfully returns DD_Manufacturer1 


    var SelectModel = ?
         $('#phSelect').append("<input type='hidden' id='hidden-dvModel' value='" + SelectModel + "' />");


}
```

I thought the best way to do this would to just preform a wildcard selection and check if it is visible, then get its selected value.

So how would I preform a wildcard selection of any element whoose ID begins with "DD", that is visible, and then get the selected value of it?

**var SelectModel = $("[id^=DD_]:visible option:selected").val(); returns "undefined"**

Comment: To get asp.net generated Id on the client side, you can use <%# control.ClientID %>; or use <pages clientIDMode="Static" /> inside web.config; btw, $("*[id^=dd]:visible option:selected").val() is working fine on my FF10

Comment: Please include the generated HTML so we can see what you're dealing with.  Actual HTML is way more valuable than lots of words trying to describe what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
var SelectModel = $("[id*=DD_]:visible option:selected").val();
```

That's because `ASP.NET WebForms` usually prepends IDs with the ID of content place holders, giving your elements fugly names like `ctl_ContentPlaceHolder01_DD_Manufacturer1`.